# JSON.parse Unexpected Token xmlhttprequest and node.js

Tags: json, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, body-parser

I'm trying to send a number from a javascript file to a node.js server (with express and body-parser modules installed), do a small calculation and return the result, updating an html field. I get the following error: *Unexpected token 0 in JSON at position 0*, even after removing all JSON.stringify and JSON.parse commands in the code.

The following files are being used (with index.js in the root directory /app):

**index.js**

```
//////////////////// Module Initializations ////////////////////

var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

//////////////////// Backend Functions ////////////////////

function secret_calculation(num)
{
    var result = num * 5;    
    return result;
}

//////////////////// Running Server ////////////////////

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Static'));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('Static/app.html', {root : __dirname});
});

app.listen(3000);

console.log('\n\n -------- S E R V E R   R U N N I N G -------- \n\n');

//////////////////// Settings for Data Transfer ////////////////////

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // to restrict api calls to the ones coming from your website
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
});

//////////////////// AJAX Requests ////////////////////

app.post("/num", function(req, res) {
    var num = parseInt(JSON.parse(req.body));
    result = secret_calculation(num);
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

**Static/client_server_comms.js**

```
function request_handler(theUrl, data, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        {
            callback(JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText));
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open('POST', theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}

function secret_calculation_(num, ans)
{
    request_handler("/num", num, function(result) {ans.innerHTML = result;});
}
```

**Static/app.js**

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", get_input);

function get_input()
{
    user_input = parseInt(document.getElementById("in_put").value);
    user_input = user_input || 0;
    ans = document.getElementById("answer");

    secret_calculation_(user_input, ans);
}
```

**Static/app.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id="in_put" type="text" maxlength="3" size="5" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');" >
    <span> x 5 = </span><span id="answer"></span>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="Calculate">

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="client_server_comms.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

There appears to be an issue with the format JSON is trying to parse (happening between the xmlhttprequest and the app.post). I've applied solutions from similar problems on stack exchange but no dice.

The error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 0 in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/Users/Mick/Desktop/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)
    at parse (/Users/Mick/Desktop/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /Users/Mick/Desktop/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/Users/Mick/Desktop/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/Users/Mick/Desktop/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/Mick/Desktop/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
```

Comment: Inside app.post("/num"), what are you getting when you do console.log(req.body)?

Comment: Just the same errors:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 0 in JSON at position 0
    
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

    at createStrictSyntaxError (/Users/Rob/Desktop/app2/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)

    at parse (/Users/Rob/Desktop/app2/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)

Comment: That indicates the request contains invalid JSON. Can you post screenshot of the request's payload from the DevTools network panel?

Comment: Seems like you are not passing valid JSON data, please checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are not passing JSON data on request. If your num = 5 then you are passing JSON.stringify(5) as req.body, which is not valid JSON.

Please see the modified code on the client side:

```
function request_handler(theUrl, data, callback)
    {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            {
                callback(JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText));
            }
        }

        xmlHttp.open('POST', theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        //xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify({num: data}))

    }

    function secret_calculation_(num, ans)
    {
        request_handler("/num", num, function(data) {ans.innerHTML = data.result;});
    }
```

On server side inside app.post("/num"), use following:

```
app.post("/num", function(req, res) {
    var data = validateJSON(req.body);
    var num = parseInt(data.num);
    result = secret_calculation(num);
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ result: result }));
});
```

Where validateJSON is a function which can be defined as:

```
function validateJson(data){
    var jsonData;
    try {
        jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        jsonData = data;
    }
    return jsonData;
};
```

Comment: That seemed to work! (note: renamed the function to "validateJSON" in order to match the call). The answer shows up correctly in html on the client side, but still in the log it shows "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"